# How to import sub objects

Tags: javascript

Given these exports in a plugin

```
// Imagine these inner functions are written somewhere
export const WindowFunctions={
   maximize: maximizeFunction,
   minimize: minimizeFunction
}

export const FileFunctions={
   open: openFileFunction,
   close: closeFileFunction
}

// Pretend there is 20 other exports here

export default{
   WindowFunctions,
   FileFunctions,
   // imagine those 20 other exports here too
}
```

When using require, you could access them with

`const {maximize} = require('yourPlugin').WindowFunctions`

How can this be achieved with `import` instead?

So far I have been doing this

```
import {WindowFunctions} from 'yourPlugin'
const maximize = WindowFunctions.maximize
```

Is there a nicer way to import these?

Thanks

Comment: You can't https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_can-i-use-destructuring-in-an-import-statement

Comment: In RequireJS/CommonJS export is an object but in ES6, export is a list not an object. It's confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import {WindowFunctions: {maximize}} from 'yourPlugin'
```

ES2015 named imports do not destructure. Use another statement for destructuring after the import.